# AWS Neptune Timeout simple query

Tags: amazon-web-services, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I have a fairly straightforward neptune query, gets the next 5 nodes

```
this.g.V(id).repeat(__.inE().outV()).emit().times(depth).tree().by(__.valueMap(true));
```

My graph is currently small, around 3500 nodes.  The query generally takes < 1 second to run.  In my logs i see successful calls taking < 1 second, then 5 minutes later, it times out after 30 seconds.  Then a call 2 minutes later works.

I'm not sure at this point what to check; I'm following the guidelines at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/lambda-functions-examples.html where I create the connection outside of the lambda handler for reuse.  I'm about to try recreating the connection on every lambda call, but wanted to know if there was anything else that could possibly cause this timeout.   I checked cloudwatch and my GremlinRequestsPerSec was only 2.5 max for the past 12 hours.

Comment: What size Neptune instance are you using?  And what is the concurrency of your Lambda function?

Comment: As to the connection timeout.  If a connection is idle for 20 minutes, Neptune will automatically close the connection.  If using IAM sessioned credentials, Neptune will close the connection when the expiry hits for the credential session.  If not using sessioned credentials, Neptune will close the connection after 10 days.

Comment: its the "serverless" instance size, `Instance class
db.serverless`.  as for connection idle, the time frame of connectionmade->working->timeout->working is less than 10 minutes.  if there was a expiry, i'd expect that it would give me some sort of auth error instead of just at imeout

Comment: If Neptune closes the connection due to idle timeout or because of expired connections, you're just going to get an 'Connection Closed' error the next time you submit a query.  You need to ensure your code has reconnect logic to handle these (as is shown in the Lambda examples you previously referenced).  I'd like to check the server side logs of your cluster to see what might be happening here.  Do you have the ability to open a support case?

Comment: thanks for the ideas, it seemed like in the end the cause was a separate query that was hitting concurrent exceptions and causing some sort of network overload.  fixing that concurrent modification exception made this issue go away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a separate concurrent modification exception/retry was causing the normal query to timeout.

Comment: Great to hear to that you found the root cause!